# HTTP Error 400 when trying to send json data with urllib2 to toggl api

Tags: python, json, urllib2

When using the following code to connect to the [toggl api](http://www.toggl.com/public/api) I connect and am authorised just fine.

```
username = token
password = 'api_token'
url = 'http://www.toggl.com/api/v3/tasks.json'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
auth_string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % auth_string)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
```

When I try to start a new task I have to send data in json format. To test, I created my json object and added the data to my Request object

```
data = simplejson.dumps({
    'task':{
        'duration': 1,
        'billable': True,
        'start': '2010-02-12T16:19:45+02:00',
        'description': 'This is a test task',
    }
})
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
```

But now the only response I recieve is "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request". Can someone please point me to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](http://www.toggl.com/public/api), you're missing at least a header. Try:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {"Content-type": "application/json"})
```

If that's not enough, try using [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2#urllib2.Request) on data. If that's still not enough, add a user:password to the request, like in the API example.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the header. Now I am getting a 500 error, which makes me think that there is a problem with my json object that I am passing.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out. Thanks to TryPyPy, I needed to add a 'Content-type' header to my request.

I had to strip any newline and linefeed characters from my authentication string.

```
auth_string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).strip()
```